# Importing XFA form into AEM, change event hander doesn't fire

Tags: forms, adobe, xfa, adaptive-layout

I have an XFA form (authored in Adobe Designer ES4) with a change event handler defined on a field.  When the form is rendered as a PDF and opened in Reader, the change event handler works fine.

However, when importing the XFA into AEM forms (Adobe Experience Manager Forms), adding the field to the AEM form works, but the change event doesn't fire when it is supposed to.  I had a change listener setup on a drop-down list.  I tried the simple case of a javascript pop-up on any change, but no luck.  (Pop-ups do work in AEM)

Offering bounty if someone can reproduce the error, and provide the solution for it.  It will probably need some customization in AEM.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you create an Adaptive Form using XFA, change script written in XFA is not executed for all the fields. It is fired only for Radio Buttons and Check Buttons.